# Apache doesn't work after updating to php7 on osx 10.11

Tags: php, macos, apache, apache2

After updating to php7 on osx, php -v returns this:

> dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libxml2/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
>   Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php   Reason: Incompatible library
>   version: php requires version 12.0.0 or later, but libxml2.2.dylib
>   provides version 10.0.0 Trace/BPT trap: 5

Also my localhost receives:

> You don't have permission to access / on this server. Additionally, a
>   403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an
>   ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Did you update using brew?

Comment: @ChrisBanks i used curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.0

Comment: I'd suggest installing the package manager brew: http://brew.sh/ then installing php7 with that.

Comment: Just a nitpick: Apache seems to work just fine. The installed PHP doesn't.